Dealing with old MSE questions specific to Stack Overflow
It seems that many years ago, MSE and MSO didn't have a separate identity. As a result, MSE has been left with probably thousands of questions - a significant percentage of them - which logically belong on MSO instead.
I base this claim primarily on the popularity of the stack-overflow tag, described thus:

USING THIS TAG IS NOT THE SAME THING AS ASKING ON STACK OVERFLOW. YOU ARE ON META STACK EXCHANGE, WHERE MOST PROGRAMMING QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Questions specific to stackoverflow.com should be asked on meta.stackoverflow.com; such questions will be closed here. This is for questions about the Stack Overflow site that still relate to the SE network as a whole. Questions about Stack Overflow (the company) should be tagged [company] instead.

This tag description strongly suggests that there isn't really any good use for this tag for new questions: if the question relates to the entire network, e.g. it's about general policy for asking questions, then it's not really actually about Stack Overflow i.e. it doesn't matter where the motivating example was posted. Further, from my experience, most of the questions thus tagged really are specific to Stack Overflow. (The few exceptions seem to be along the lines of "why does X technical detail of the site software work/look different on Stack Overflow compared to other network sites?"; but in these cases I still don't think the tag is particularly helpful.)
Although the network used to have a system for one-time migrations for new sites, that's no longer the case - and in any event, Stack Overflow wasn't new at the time of the split. Ordinary migration is also not an option since essentially all of these questions are over 60 days old.
Recently I have noticed some efforts on MSE, and some push-back against those efforts, to close those old questions, as they "relate to only one specific network site". (See for example Why does Stack Overflow work? which was recently closed and then promptly re-opened.) This seems like a lot of potential churn that accomplishes very little - is there a good reason to prevent further answers to these questions, that doesn't equally apply to any other question of similar age?
Meanwhile, the lack of migration options causes a real problem for MSO: duplicates can't be closed cross-site, so when someone asks substantially the same question where it belongs, it can't be redirected to the old Q&A. Do we have any mitigations for this?

Sometimes I can't tell the difference between MSO and MSE. For example this MSO post, in my head this post should have been made on(or migrated to) MSE. The behavior described on post affects all sites on the SE network

@AugustoVasques users can always report bugs on their site on the per-site meta. The onus is not on them to figure out whether it is site-specific or network-wide. As for migrations: if a post is on-topic elsewhere doesn't make the post off-topic on the site. I see not much harm in having one ore more per-site-meta posts and one on MSE that glues the per-site-meta ones together.

If people want to close them, okay. I don’t think it’s necessary but it’s fine. However I strongly object if that proceeds to deletion, which sometimes has a tendency to happen. I don’t want swaths of the history of the network to be deleted, either here or on MSO, because they aren’t relevant to the sites as they exist today. I’m often voting to reopen these because I worry about deletions and I’d like to block that, even though I’m ambivalent about the closure itself.

Some of them can probably easily be made ontopic here by replacing SO with SO/SE and not much more. However the error has been made in the past when MSE was born and people did not split the history between MSE and MSO correctly.

According to the faq staff can apparently circumvent the 60 day age limit on migrating posts. But it's only done in very, very rare cases. So, I'd say, start a discussion on MSO if you think there are any old posts that are really needed/wanted there, listing compelling arguments, and if the sentiment is shared there, flag the post with a link to the discussion. Mods can kick it up to staff with a request to take a look.
As for closing such posts, I see no problems with it, as long as users don't go deliberately looking for them and flooding the queues. But if an user or a spammer or a bot necromances such a post, putting it on the active page, or if it seems to be causing confusion in any other way, closing it seems fine. Not everyone is always going to be fully aware that they're on an old post that's from before "the split" (or even know what that is), and having it closed on the active page and preventing further necromancing seems fine to me.

"deliberately looking for them and flooding the queues" - I think that's the case here, at least a while ago when there were like 20 items in the close votes queue. Maybe not flood, but still - I don't think it's correct to go look for those just in order to close them.

@ShadowWizard it is not. I shall look into that further.
